# Ends with CSS selector not compatible with last-of-type?

Tags: html, css

I could be doing this completely wrong but I can't seem to get the CSS to attach itself to the `last-of-type` with an "ends with" `[class*="name"]`.

Is this the right approach?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to generalise my code and limit using `:nth-child()` which uses hardcoded variables.

```css
.form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.form-group .form-control {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.form-group[class*="name"],
.form-group[class*="password"] {
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.form-group[class*="name"]:last-of-type, .form-group[class*="password"]:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group name-first">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group name-last">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group password">
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group password-confirm">
  <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control btn btn-alternative" type="submit" value="Register">
</div>
```

Comment: As stated in the recent edit, I'm trying generalise my code and not use hard coded values for certain elements. @CBroe

Comment: Doesn’t change one bit about the general impossibility of the thing to begin with; duplicate explains why.

Comment: last-of-type, first-of-type, nth-child, first-child, etc, etc ---> all are the same and don't tell me it's not a duplicate because it's a perfect one and you cannot do what you have in mind